# Large 250 GB Mysql Database of online shop- Indexing Needed

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Hello to everyone and happy new year.
I am quite new to MySQL databases and I need a bit of help and advice if possible. I currently created a very large e-shop with over 250 gb worth of products and still growing. I have optimized my dedicated server and WordPress website to the best options but I am still not satisfied with the speed of my website and some of its features like when i use the search bar is extremely slow. I understand that I need MySQL optimizations, which I have done some of them but I am  not sure how to proceed even further maybe with more optimizations or indexing the tables. I don't know how to do it effectively and what keys and commands to use on so big database to make the indexing correctly.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Index columns used in queries, that of course means you need to know which columns will benefit a query. So we cannot help

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses an EAV schema design, which is inherently inefficient.  To top it off, the `INDEXes` it uses on `wp_postmeta` could be made better:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: Hello and my apologies to my very late reply. Due to corona virus issues i had a lot of problems and couldn't work. Thank you very much for your reply and the time you took to answer me. I will be checking it. Good luck. Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on your success with your e-shop!

The most common optimization is to create indexes. Which indexes you need depends on what queries you are running.

There's no way anyone on Stack Overflow can recommend specific optimizations, since we know nothing about your tables or queries.

I made a presentation about the process of optimizing with indexes years ago, but the principles haven't changed:

[How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)

Video of the presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Hello and my apologies to my very late reply. Due to corona virus issues i had a lot of problems and couldn't work. Thank you very much for your reply and the time you took to answer me. I will be checking it. Good luck. Kind Regards

Comment: No problem. I wish you good health and success with your e-shop.